# Regex pattern allowing certain special characters

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

I am using the regex pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*-_&\\\\]+$`for password validation in edittext android. The problem i am facing where my regex fails to restrict characters like `,;/` (i.e this should be restricted but currently allowing). Kindly please help with this. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem is your use of unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class**. Use this instead:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*_&\\\\-]+$
```

Hyphen when used in the middle of regex behaves like a range i.e. `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` etc. In your regex is making a range of `*-_`.

Between `*` and `_` it will match characters like: `:`, `;`, `/` etc. Look at this ascii chart for reference (it will match everything in this table):

```
                    42  *    43  +    44  ,    45  -    46  .    47  /
  48  0    49  1    50  2    51  3    52  4    53  5    54  6    55  7
  56  8    57  9    58  :    59  ;    60  <    61  =    62  >    63  ?
  64  @    65  A    66  B    67  C    68  D    69  E    70  F    71  G
  72  H    73  I    74  J    75  K    76  L    77  M    78  N    79  O
  80  P    81  Q    82  R    83  S    84  T    85  U    86  V    87  W
  88  X    89  Y    90  Z    91  [    92  \    93  ]    94  ^    95  _
```

**PS:** Your regex can be shortened to:

```
^[\\w@.#$%^&*&\\\\-]+$
```

Comment: Very nice breakdown of the ASCII chart. I would also like to point out the doubled up \\.

Comment: Yes definitely escaped hyphen also works e.g. `^[\\w@.#$%^&\-*&\\\\]+$`

Comment: I was referring to the end \\\\ which is redundant.

Comment: what is the difference in adding \\\\ and \\??

Comment: Your shortened regex will not work. It escapes the second \ at the beginning instead of matching a word character

Comment: i added because code is not working if i add \ alone

Comment: RegExr.com. Put the regex in at the top and hover over all the parts of it. It will break it down for you and tell you exactly what everything means.

Comment: @AlexanderKerchum: I used `\\w` because question was tagged as Java.

Comment: ah. Okay. I was looking at it from the regex only point of view.

Comment: @anubhava can you please post a regex to restrict space also in the above regex. It would be helpful for me too

Comment: sorry it should allow spaces anywhere

Comment: does it allow space anywhere in between??

Answer (score 1):

The key is in this little part here `*-_` 
This is a range of characters from "*" to "_". If you wanted to have just "*", "-", and "_" you need to escape the "-". You also had a repeate character at the end "\"

The working regex would then be: `^[a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*\-_&\\]+$`

For future reference you can use [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/). It breaks them down very nicely and explains them when you hover over parts of the regex.